# Testing function chains using Sinon.JS

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon, stub, sinon-chai

How can I test a function like the following using Sinon.JS?

```
export function getToken(done) {
  const kc = Keycloak(config)
  kc.init({ onLoad: 'login-required' })
    .success(authenticated => {
      authenticated ? done(null, kc.token) : done(new Error('Some error!'), null)
    })
    .error(() => {
      done(new Error('Some error'), null)
    })
}
```

I tried doing something like the following, to no avail:

```
it('should return access_token', () => {
    const mockKeycloak = sinon.stub(Keycloak, 'init').returns({
      success: () => (true)
    })
    getToken(function () {})
    expect(mockKeycloak.callCount).to.equal(1)
  })
```

Basically Keycloak from [keycloak-js](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-js-bower/blob/master/dist/keycloak.js) is an IIFE but even after trying to stub the `Keycloak` object on the *window* reference, I can't make it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who lands here, this is what I did:

Since Keycloak is an IIFE, it overrides the stubbed object once we do

```
const kc = Keycloak(config)
```

Therefore I just exported this object `kc` from the source and stubbed the `init` method on it and it worked just fine!